testing for a correlation between a real number and percentage accuracy
So, I have some data from a citizen science survey where participants were tasked with collecting and identifying scat from 5 different sites.
I want to see if there is a correlation between:
The number of fox scat samples collected from a site
The accuracy (expressed as a %) with which participants were able to identify pine marten scat from a a site
How should I go about this? I'm guessing it'll be a Spearman/Pearson test, depending on whether the data is normally distributed. Is this correct? Should I convert the accuracy values to decimals, rather than percentages?

No real data are ever normally distributed. Statistical model assumptions are idealised thought constructs. Note that for just computing correlations you don't necessarily need a test (and neither will a test tell you whether there is correlation or not; it will only tell you whether data are compatible with the possibility of no correlation).
The decision between Pearson and Spearman correlation is basically a decision whether you are interested in specifically linear (or close to linear) relation, or generally monotonic relation. The former is measured by Pearson, the latter by Spearman. Spearman is preferred if you have extreme outliers, as these may unduly influence Pearson.
Converting any values in a linear way will not change results, neither for Pearson nor for Spearman.
